# Sentry version incompatibility

Tags: flutter, version, sentry

Sentry latest version is incompatible with http plugin and if another version of sentry is used then it is also not compatible with rest of the other already used packages in project.
Even without version I tried to get its compatible version but this also not worked.

Comment: What version of the Sentry SDK for Flutter are you using? And what version of Flutter and of the Google Maps plugin?

Comment: hi, i m trying to use latest sentry version 6.2.2. flutter version used - 2.5.3 and http plugin version used - 0.12.2

Comment: Use Sentry Flutter SDK 4.0.6 https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dart/releases/tag/4.0.6
You lose bug fixes and new features due to being behind 2 major versions tho.

Comment: hi manoel, tried your solution of using sentry version 4.0.6 but its getting incompatible with package_info plugin

Answer (score 0):

> This is because Sentry uses http: ^0.13.0 because that's the earliest version which is null safe. The user uses a pretty outdated version of http.

Got the reply from GitHub: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dart/issues/694

Comment: tried with http: ^0.13.0, but now http is getting incompatible with flutter_google_maps:^4.0.0